# No consigo obtener los grupos de usuarios de Azure AD en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de obtener todos los grupos de usuarios que iniciaron sesión y para eso estoy usando algunos ejemplos:

Uno de ellos es

```
foreach (IdentityReference group in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
{
  groups.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
}
```

Pero tengo éste error:

> namespace name 'HttpContext' does not existe in the namespace 'System.web'.

Intenté agregar la referencia en mi proyecto pero no aparece en la lista, por lo que asumo que se agregó cuando creé el proyecto.

```
string username = User.FindFirst("name")?.Value;

List<string> result = new List<string>();
WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(username);

foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
{
    try
    {
        result.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
result.Sort();

groups = result;
```

Tengo éste mensaje:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

```
var g = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "groups").ToList();
    foreach(var nom in g){
        grup += nom + " - ";
    }
```

Pero tengo éste error:

> Exception: Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.

Vi que en _LoginPartial (la vista que se crea de forma predeterminada cuando asigna Microsoft como autenticación de inicio de sesión) tiene `@User.FindFirst("name")?.Value`, que trae el nombre de usuario. Intenté algo así pero no pude hacerlo, uno uno de éstos ejemplos es `@User.FindFirst("groups")?.Value`.

Llevo dias intentandolo y no consigo hacerlo. Leí la documentación de Azure e incluso la de Microsoft nos la da pero no ayuda.

Me podria ayudar cómo es que puedo obtener los grupos de un usuario que se logea con microsoft en mi aplicacion web?

No es posible utilizar `Roles` porque no lo estoy pagando, y la idea es no hacerlo si es posible hacerlo con `Groups`

Comment: Eh puesto unos Loggers y éste es el problema que estoy teniendo: **Authorization_RequestDenied Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. azure ad asp.net.**.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de obtener los grupos de usuarios puede ser:

```
public List<string> GetUserGroups(string userId)
{
    var results = new List<string>();
    try 
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userId))
            {
                if (user != null) { results = user.GetAuthorizationGroups().Select(x => x.DistinguishedName).ToList(); }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {               
        throw ex;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Basandome en tu codigo podria ser:

```
string username = User.FindFirst("name")?.Value;

List<string> result = new List<string>();
//WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(username);
result = GetUserGroups(username);    
result.Sort();

groups = result;
```

`UserPrincipal` esta en `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`